# PDF of sum of independent exponential r.v.s of different parameter values

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

If we have N independent exponential random variables of different parameter values:

$x_1$ ~ exp($m_1$), $x_2$ ~ exp($m_2$), ..., $x_N$ ~ exp($m_N$)

Is there a closed form (and SIMPLE) answer for the pdf of the sum of those random variables, i.e., the pdf of $\sum_{i=1}^{N} {x_i}$? If not, is there an approximation (with a reference if available) where this pdf is approximated using another known pdf?

Thanks

Comment: Good question. $$M_{S_n}(t)=\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_i-t}=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac {\alpha_i\lambda_i}{\lambda_i-t}$$ for $\alpha_i=\prod_{j\ne i}(\lambda_j-\lambda_i)^{-1}$. This yields $$f_{S_n}(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_if_{X_i}(x)$$
i.e. a linear combination of original pdfs. You can check that the coefficient corresponding to the smallest $\lambda_i$ is always positive (agreeing with expected asymptotic behavior of $f_{S_n}(x)$ as $x\to\infty$) and then coefficients alternate signs. The approach can be extended to equal $\lambda$'s.

Comment: Although the derivation of the PDF of the sum using MGFs in the Comment by @A.S. is quite elegant, perhaps see `http://www.maths.bris.ac.uk/~mb13434/sumexp.pdf` for additional discussion of this PDF.

Comment: @A.S.: Maybe $\prod_{j \ne i}\lambda_j(\lambda_j - \lambda_i)^{-1}$ (unit-less constant)?? Please check for sure.

Comment: @BruceET you are absolutely right - I omitted the pre-factor and dimension analysis clearly points to it.

Comment: @A.S. Thanks. Made the same mistake until density curve wouldn't fit histogram in my simulation.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, if the rates $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = \cdots = \lambda$ are equal, then
$S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \sim Gamma(n, rate = \lambda).$ For $n=2,\;$ $\lambda_1 = 1/4,$ and $\lambda_2 = 1/5,$ here is a simulation of
the distribution of the sum that approximates the density function.

```
 lam1 = 1/4;  lam2 = 1/5;  m = 10^6;  
 x1 = rexp(m, lam1);  x2 = rexp(m, lam2);  s = x1 + x2
 mean(s);  sd(s)
 hist(s, br=50, prob=T, col="wheat")
   c1 = lam2/(lam2 - lam1);  c2 = lam1/(lam1 - lam2)
   curve(c1*dexp(x,lam1)+c2*dexp(x,lam2), 0,max(s), 
      n = 1001, lwd=2, col="blue", add=T)
```

[image]

Notes: (1) In R, the `curve` statement requires the
use of the parameter `x`.

(2) Our factors `c1` and `c2` are not exactly the same as the $\alpha_i$
in the Comment.

(3) Because of the subtractions in the denominators, one cannot simply set $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = \lambda$
in the expression for the PDF of $S_2$ to get the PDF of
$Gamma(2, \lambda).$