# Find $ \mathbb P \{ 2S_1 + 3S_2 \gt 2 \} $.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, poisson-process, exponential-distribution

**The Problem:**

Consider a Poisson process with $\lambda = 2$. Let $S_k$ denote the waiting time until the $k$th event. So, $S_k = \sum_{i=1}^{k} T_i $, where each $T_i$ represents the interarrival time between the $(i-1)th$ and $i$th event. It follows that $T_k, k = 1, 2, 3, ... ,$ are iid exponential random variables having mean $1/\lambda$.

Find $ \mathbb P \{ 2S_1 + 3S_2 \gt 2 \} $.

**SOLUTION**

I have the solution, but I'm wondering why the following approach doesn't work. I tried just decomposing the $S_i$'s into $T$'s. Observe:

$$ 2S_1 + 3S_2 = 2(T_1) + 3(T_1 + T_2) = 2\text{Expo}(2) + 3[\text{Expo}(2) + \text{Expo}(2)] $$

$$ = \text{Expo}(1) + 3[2(\text{Expo}(2)] = \text{Expo}(1) + 3[\text{Expo}(1)] $$

$$  = \text{Expo}(1) + \text{Expo}(1/3). $$

If this were the case, I could easily find the CDF of this sum of exponential random variables and proceed accordingly. However, this does not yield the correct solution, and I'm not sure why it doesn't. Is it, perhaps, because $T_1$ is (clearly) not independent of $T_1$, or something?

Comment: I'd say that's certainly a problem.  I'd have characterized the random expression $2S_1+3S_2$ in your terminology as $5\text{Expo}(2)+3\text{Expo}(2) = \text{Expo}(2/5)+\text{Expo}(2/3)$.  Be aware that $+$ in this case means concatenation (therefore the distributions must be convolved).

Comment: For the PDF of the sum of exponentials with different rates, please see `http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1681960/`.

Comment: @BrianTung Wait... how did you arrive at that expression?

Comment: @thisisourconcerndude: I began as you did, with $2S_1+3S_2 = 2T_1+3(T_1+T_2)$, and continue with $2T_1+3(T_1+T_2) = 5T_1+3T_2$.  Now, $T_1$ and $T_2$ are i.i.d. exponentially with parameter $2$.

Comment: @BrianTung Oh. Let me see if I understand this. So, we can add the two $T_1$'s as we normally add things because they're not only distributed in the same manner, but they are in fact the same exact mathematical object, in some sense (i.e. they're not independent). For example, if we knew that they were both $independent$ exponential RVs with the same parameter, then they're sum would be a gamma RV; but $T_1$ and $T_1$ are obviously completely dependent -- their correlation is $1$, I suppose one'd say. Do I have this correct?

Comment: @thisisourconcerndude: I think so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your notation is not good.
You claim that 
$$\text{Expo}(2)+\text{Expo}(2) = 2\text{Expo}(2)$$
which is false.
If $X,Y$ are iid Exp($\lambda$), then 
$$X+Y\sim\text{Gamma}(2,\lambda),$$
***not***
$$X+Y = 2X$$
***nor***
$$X+Y\sim\,2\text{Expo}(\lambda).$$

---

Further it will be a good exercise for you to show that if $c>0$, $X\sim \text{Exp}(\lambda)$, $Z\sim \text{Gamma}(n,\lambda)$, then
$$cX\sim\text{Exp}(\lambda/c)$$
and 
$$cZ\sim\text{Gamma}(n,\lambda/c).$$

Comment: Ah. I see. I always get confused about what operations are permitted with random variables.

Comment: @this Please see my edit. If you find this answer satisfying, please consider giving a [check mark](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Good luck.

Comment: Oh, you'll get the check mark. I have to wait a few minutes for it to allow me to mark it checked.

Comment: @this Also note that by Exp($\lambda$), I mean that the mean is $1/\lambda$, and Gamma($n,\lambda$), the mean is $n/\lambda$. I believe the notation varies. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Comment:  Here is a simulated answer for the case $\lambda = 5,$ against which you can check
your analytic answer (2 or 3 place accuracy).

```
  t1 = rexp(10^6, 5);  t2 = rexp(10^6, 5)
  mean(5*t1 + 3*t2 > 2)
  ## 0.284454
  s1 = t1;  s2 = t1 + t2
  mean(2*s1 + 3*s2 > 2)
  ## 0.284454
  y = 2*s1 + 3*s2
  hist(y, prob=T, col="wheat")
  abline(v = 2, col="green4")
```

[image]