# Density of the Sum of Two Exponential Random Variable

Tags: probability, random-variables, density-function, exponential-distribution

For independent random variables X ∼ Exp(1) and Y ∼ Exp(2), find the density of the random variable Z = X + Y .

My work:
For any exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$ the function is
$f(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}$

$f_x(x) =  e^{-x}$

$f_y(x) = 2e^{-2y}$

Therefore the joint density function is: $f_{xy}(x) = 2e^{-x-2y} , x,y\ge 0$ and $0$ otherwise

After this I do not know how to $f_{X+Y}$

Comment: You can learn about "convolution function"

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1681960/pdf-of-sum-of-independent-exponential-r-v-s-of-different-parameter-values?noredirect=1#comment3446436_1681960 including correction to the main (1st) *comment*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use convolution and get
$$f_Z(z) = \int_0^z f_X(x)f_{Y}(-x+z)|1|\,dx.$$

I suspect that you might rather compute the cdf of $Z$
$$P(Z\leq z) = P(X+Y\leq z).$$

Comment: I ended up getting $f_Z(z) =2ze^{-z}   for X+Y \le z$ is this correct?

Comment: I don't think so. Note $f_z$ is the pdf, $F_Z$ is the cdf.

Comment: By the way, the answer is $-2[e^{-2z}-e^{-z}]$.

Comment: I integrated the pdf to get the cdf.I got the answer was that you just posted. Thank you!

Comment: Note to reader: the upper limit of $z$ in the integration is due to the fact that the exponential distribution is only supported on $z \geq 0$, not by definition of convolution.